# Why an element that can be identified by a Xpath expression on Chrome Dev tool search box cannot be found by Selenium VBA script?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to read the Recommendation Rating from yahoo finance webpage with the following code:

```
Sub testSelenium()

Dim driver As New webdriver
driver.Start "chrome"

driver.Get "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL"

'cookies consent
driver.FindElementByCss("[value=reject]").Click

MsgBox driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@data-test='rec-rating-txt']").IsPresent

End Sub
```

After running this VBA code, I was expecting to get a TRUE result on the `MsgBox` but I got `NoSuchElementError`.

So, What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: MsgBox driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@data-test='rec-rating-txt']").IsPresent

Comment: Having located the element, it isn't within your specified iframe. Have you tried getting the element without switching frame?

Comment: yes, The element is there and the Xpath for it is correct but the iframe is incorrect (it's outside the iframe specified). I'll correct the problem description. However, without switching frame, the problem remains the same